# Manipulate and ListPlot

Tags: plotting

I have a $300$ by $2$ matrix called `r` which its elements depend on parameter `g`. I would like to plot this matrix and change the `g` to see how the graph changes. I have used this code:

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[r], {g, 0, 10}]
```

However, nothing happens. If I determine the parameter `g`, then I can plot it with `ListPlot[r]`. But, when I use manipulate, I cannot plot it.

Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post short, but complete examples for questions like this.  Here the definition of `r` is missing, so I could only guess at what was going wrong.  If we knew the value of `r` (not a 300 by 2 matrix, but a short one, say, 3 by 2), then we could give a definite solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to inline the value of `r`, like this:

```
With[{rr = r}, Manipulate[ListPlot[rr], {g, 0, 10}]]
```

This'll make sure that the value of `r` is substituted in first, and `g` only after.

Comment: This code works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming r can be defined:

```
r = Table[{x, Sin[g x]}, {x, 0, 300}];
```

Use something like this:

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[r /. g -> gg], {gg, 1, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The same results is obtained as Szabolcs answer, and I don't know if there are advantages/disadvantages to either solution.

Comment: This code works. Thank you. I cannot add another parameter like g and plot it by changing the two parameters. However, the other answer by Szabolcs can be easily generalize to two parameter.