# Manipulation of ListPlot of an imported list versus first elements

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, manipulate

I have seen [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40863/manipulate-and-listplot)& [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10604/how-are-parameters-evaluated-for-a-plot-in-manipulate) but I could not find an answer helping me. I have created (by another program) a list as below:

```
list={{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0,0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0,0}, 
 {0.1, -0.1}, {0.1,- 0.0866025}, {0.1, -0.0866025}, {0.1,-0.05}, {0.1, -0.05}, {0.1, 0}, {0.1, 0},{0.1, 0}, {0.1, 0}, {0.1, 0}, {0.1, 0}, {0.1, 0.05}, {0.1, 0.05}, {0.1,0.0866025}, {0.1, 0.0866025}, {0.1, 0.1},
 {0.2, -0.2}, {0.2, -0.173205}, {0.2, -0.173205}, {0.2, -0.1},{0.2, -0.1}, {0.2, 0}, {0.2, 0}, {0.2, 0}, {0.2, 0},{0.2, 0}, {0.2,0}, {0.2, 0.1}, {0.2, 0.1}, {0.2, 0.173205}, {0.2, 0.173205},{0.2,0.2}, 
{0.3, -0.3}, {0.3, -0.259808}, {0.3, -0.259808}, {0.3,-0.15}, {0.3, -0.15}, {0.3, 0}, {0.3, 0}, {0.3, 0}, {0.3, 0}, {0.3, 0}, {0.3, 0}, {0.3, 0.15}, {0.3, 0.15}, {0.3, 0.259808}, {0.3, 0.259808}, {0.3,  0.3},
 {0.4, -0.4}, {0.4, -0.34641}, {0.4, -0.34641}, {0.4, -0.2},{0.4, -0.2}, {0.4, 0}, {0.4, 0}, {0.4, 0}, {0.4, 0}, {0.4, 0}, {0.4,0}, {0.4, 0.2}, {0.4, 0.2}, {0.4, 0.34641}, {0.4, 0.34641}, {0.4,0.4}, 
 {0.5, -0.5}, {0.5, -0.433013}, {0.5, -0.433013}, {0.5,-0.25}, {0.5, -0.25}, {0.5, 0}, {0.5, 0}, {0.5, 0}, {0.5, 0}, {0.5,0}, {0.5, 0},   {0.5, 0.25}, {0.5, 0.25}, {0.5, 0.433013}, {0.5,0.433013}, {0.5, 0.5}}
```

This above list is partial part of the main list that has been prevented to be presented completely for short asking the main question.

I wanted to manipulate `ListPlot` in an order in which in any step of manipulation the desired case is to show a set of numbers with the same first elements for example: `{0.1, -0.1}, {0.1,- 0.0866025}, {0.1, -0.0866025}, {0.1,-0.05}, {0.1, -0.05}, {0.1, 0}, {0.1, 0},{0.1, 0}, {0.1, 0}, {0.1, 0}, {0.1, 0}, {0.1, 0.05}, {0.1, 0.05}, {0.1,0.0866025}, {0.1, 0.0866025}, {0.1, 0.1},` with `0.1`  or `{0.2, -0.2}, {0.2, -0.173205}, {0.2, -0.173205}, {0.2, -0.1},{0.2, -0.1}, {0.2, 0}, {0.2, 0}, {0.2, 0}, {0.2, 0},{0.2, 0}, {0.2,0}, {0.2, 0.1}, {0.2, 0.1}, {0.2, 0.173205}, {0.2, 0.173205},{0.2,0.2}` with `0.2` and I should have a control on the presentation of complete list step by step with any first elements.

The above addresses devoted to the cases in which we can write the table directly in manipulation but my `list` unfortunately imported from another program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
parameters = Union[list[[All, 1]]];

yMin = Min[list[[All, 2]]];
yMax = Max[list[[All, 2]]];
xMin = Min[list[[All, 1]]];
xMax = Max[list[[All, 1]]];

plots = Table[
   ListPlot[Select[list, #[[1]] == parameters[[i]] &], 
   PlotRange -> {{xMin, xMax}, {yMin, yMax}}], 
   {i, 1, Length@parameters}];

Manipulate[plots[[i]], {i, 1, Length@plots, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: You have generated a table from different listplots and after that manipulated them it was interesting.